# Attempting to use variables that are stored within cell data

Tags: php

I am facing a problem that doesn't allow variables retrieved from cell data to appear as the declared variable on my web page. I will post an example below ;

***email.db - Below represents the cell data for column email_body***

email_body = Hi, $name

```
$name = $row['name'];    

$messagebody = $row["email_body"];

$message = "
            <html>
            <body>
            <p>".$messagebody."</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            ;
            "
```

As you can see I'm attempting to make $row['name'] appear within $messagebody (which is text stored in a DB). The issue i'm having is that the above code will display $messagebody, but the $name variable will display as plain text and will ignore the variable.

Your help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: `</html>
            ;
            "` you should be getting a parse error about this.

Comment: What exactly do you you mean by "cell"? Or are you confusing databases with spreadsheets?

Comment: I don't see where you attempted to include `$name` here. From what I saw in edit mode, you have `email_body = Hi, $name` which is unclear for a few reasons. Are you even reading comments here?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel - I think you might not have the exact right idea about how variables are rendered inside of PHP strings.

However, there is a function called [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) that might be the tool to do what you're attempting to do!

```
sprintf (string $format [, mixed $... ])
```

The first `$format` argument in your case would be `'Hi, %s'` - the `%s` being a stand-in for *another* string, `$name`. The function would then return `'Hi, Bobby'`, were `$name` set to bobby. (And name was passed as the second arg.)

```
// Re-set the data inside of `email_body` to 'Hi, %s';
// "%s" is a placeholder that hints that a string should be placed there

$name        = $row['name'];
$messagebody = sprintf($row["email_body"], $name);
$message     = "<html>
                  <body>
                    <p>".$messagebody."</p>
                  </body>
                </html>";
```

Comment: Sincere apologies for the typo, Funk Forty Niner.

Comment: Wasn't your fault.

Comment: Who needs a linter when you have Funk Forty Niner

Comment: Hi Cameron, I'm somewhat new to PHP so you are definately right. Your answer helped a lot though. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to evaluate PHP code in a string. That is generally unsafe. Instead of that, you can replace the placeholders (e.g. `$name`) with the actual values.

Example:

```
$messagebody = "Hi, $name!"
$compiledmessagebody = preg_replace('/\$name/', 'Daniel V.', $messagebody);

$message = "
        <html>
        <head><title></title><head>
        <body>
        <p>".$compiledmessagebody."</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
```

EDIT: actually, it would be better to use a templating engine to do the above and much more out of the box. Pug goes nicely with PHP https://www.phug-lang.com/

Comment: `str_replace` would be better since you aren't using a regex.

Comment: `</html>
        ;
        "` you included the same mistake the OP did, which will cause a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

I would use HEREDOC syntax:

```
$name = $row['name'];    

$messagebody = $row['email_body'];

$message = <<<HTML

      <html>
      <body>
         <p>$messagebody</p>
      </body>
      </html>
HTML;
```

That way you don't have to worry about breaking out of strings and multi-line strings appear much neater.

Technically, you don't need to break out of a double quoted string when using a simple variable like you were doing.

With HEREDOC syntax the last HTML; needs to be pushed all the way to the left. In this case I am using `HTML` as an identifier, but you can rename the identifier to something else.